# Multiline values in kustomize environment source file

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kustomize

I'm trying to set multiline values (contents of a ca certificate file) to kustomize environment file for a particular key as displayed in the code below.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: Adding quotes to the value in some_params.env isn't working.

kustomize.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
commonLabels:
  role: authentication
bases:
- ./somebase

configMapGenerator:
- name: some-parameters
  env: some_params.env
vars:
- name: ca_contents
  objref:
    kind: ConfigMap
    name: some-parameters
    apiVersion: v1
  fieldref:
    fieldpath: data.ca_contents
configurations:
 - some_params.yaml
```

some_params.yaml

```
varReference:
- path: data/ca.pem
  kind: ConfigMap
```

some_params.env

```
ca_contents= |
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
YOUR CA CERTIFICATE CONTENTS
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Running the following command:
`kustomize build base`

Returns:
`Error: NewResMapFromConfigMapArgs: NewResMapFromConfigMapArgs: env source file: some_params.env: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" is not a valid key name: a valid environment variable name must consist of alphabetic characters, digits, '_', '-', or '.', and must not start with a digit (e.g. 'my.env-name',  or 'MY_ENV.NAME',  or 'MyEnvName1', regex used for validation is '[-._a-zA-Z][-._a-zA-Z0-9]*')`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is indentation. Kustomize thinks your *some_params.env* file consists of keys only. To be conformant with the YAML specification, multiline strings need to be indented by one tab.
So *some_params.env* should look like this:

```yaml
ca_contents= |
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  YOUR CA CERTIFICATE CONTENTS
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If you want more details on multiline strings, have a look at these sources:

- [YAML multiline strins](https://yaml-multiline.info/), an interactive explenation of how those strings have to be formatted
- [stackoverflow - How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/11908728), answer to a similar answer with in depth explanation of different ways to format multiline strings